# How do I get started on MPI on windows machine

Tags: windows, mpi, mpich

I am struggling learning MPI on Windows machine. I tried MPICH2, but failed to execute application on LAN. Can someone tell me which implementation is best supported on Windows machine? I know there are many implementations out there, but which one to choose is confusing me.

Comment: I've used MPICH2 on Windows with no problems (granted, only on a single machine, not on LAN). How exactly did you fail to execute your program? We need more info.

Comment: Thanks I got the reply [here](http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F). They do not support on Windows anymore due to lack of developer interest

Answer (score 0):

For future reference (this question is asked a lot). The standard answer you'll get when asking questions about MPICH on Windows is this:

Unfortunately, we haven't supported Windows since MPICH version 1.4.1p1. You can find out more at the FAQ page: http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F